# Populating select options with set times using JavaScript arrays?

Tags: javascript

I think this may have a simple solution but I am not sure where to go with it. I am trying to populate a `<select>` with dynamically added options from a JavaScript array (as my HTML looked really messy).

I have been looking online and seen someone suggest it could be done the way I have tried but it doesn't work (and throws no errors), but mostly I have only found solutions which do not use a hard-coded array, instead using a function to find certain times at intervals (which I don't need for this challenge).

My thoughts are that I need to convert the times, but I couldn't find anything online to tell me if arrays accept times as an input. I haven't slept well in a few days so I apologize if this is a glaringly obvious solution. Here's what I have so far... (my options are commented out on my file)

https://codepen.io/caitlinmooneyx/pen/LYRpEOv

```js
function populateTimes() {

    let startTimes = document.getElementById('stime');

    let times = ['9:00', '9:30', '10:00', '10:30', '11:00', '11:30','12:00','12:30', '13:00', '13:30', '14:00', '14:30', '15:00'];

    console.log(stime);
    startTimes.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let options = times.map(time => `<option value="${time}">${time}</option>`).join('\n');

        startTimes.innerHTML = options;
    });
}
```

```html
  <select name="stime" onclick="populateTimes()" id="stime" required>                            
                            <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose a time</option>
             <!--
                            <option value="nine">9:00</option>
                            <option value="hnine">9:30</option>
                            <option value="ten">10:00</option>
                            <option value="hten">10:30</option>
                            <option value="eleven">11:00</option>
                            <option value="heleven">11:30</option>
                            <option value="twelve">12:00</option>
                            <option value="htwelve">12:30</option>
                            <option value="one">13:00</option>
                            <option value="hone">13:30</option>
                            <option value="two">14:00</option>
                            <option value="htwo">14:30</option>
                            <option value="three">15:00</option>
-->
                        </select>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('stime').value;` <= you're getting the value and trying to treat it as an Element later.  Take the `.value` off.

Comment: You also need to do this when the document loads, not when the user clicks the select element.

Comment: Ah - duh! I just looked at that there wondering if that was the issue. A simple fix at least, thank you @Taplar

Comment: Note that the error message your code produces is `select.addEventListener is not a function`, which means you should use `console.log(select)` right before the line in question to debug this.

Comment: Okay.. it worked on the click event but since adding the onLoad (if thats even correct) it is not working now.. I will update the codepen to show.

Comment: CodePen updated to show what I mean @ChrisG

Comment: `<select>` elements do not have a load event.  `window`, `<iframe>`, `<img>` and other "resource" elements have load events.  Most elements do not.

Comment: Also, please create a runnable snippet onsite instead of linking to a codepen.

Comment: There's no onload event in your codepen, just a function that isn't called. Options are still added onclick, which on Firefox prevents selecting anything besides the first option. Working version: https://codepen.io/khrismuc/pen/PoGPwdG (script is inserted at the end of <body>, so no load event necessary)

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for your help @ChrisG it is working perfectly now. I will note this down for future reference.

Comment: And also thank you @Taplar

Comment: You're welcome :)